# How to improve neural network accuracy for a random X array where the y is modulus(X,2)?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I am learning about neural networks and I found the following code which works well with the iris dataset reaching around 99% accuracy.

However when I try to run the same network on a dummy dataset randomly generated using `get_modulus_data()` where there is correlation between the input and the output as follows, it doesn't work so well. Would anyone be able to shed a light why the neural network struggles with this type of training input?

```
# Implementation of a simple MLP network with one hidden layer. Tested on the iris data set.
# Requires: numpy, sklearn, tensorflow

# NOTE: In order to make the code simple, we rewrite x * W_1 + b_1 = x' * W_1'
# where x' = [x | 1] and W_1' is the matrix W_1 appended with a new row with elements b_1's.
# Similarly, for h * W_2 + b_2
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

RANDOM_SEED = 42
tf.set_random_seed(RANDOM_SEED)


def init_weights(shape):
    """ Weight initialization """
    weights = tf.random_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(weights)

def forwardprop(X, w_1, w_2, w_3):
    """
    Forward-propagation.
    IMPORTANT: yhat is not softmax since TensorFlow's softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits() does that internally.
    """
    h_1    = tf.nn.elu(tf.matmul(X, w_1))  # The \sigma function
    h_1    = tf.nn.dropout(h_1,0.5)
    h_2    = tf.nn.elu(tf.matmul(h_1, w_2))  # The \sigma function
    h_2    = tf.nn.dropout(h_2,0.5)
    yhat = tf.matmul(h_2, w_3)  # The \varphi function
    return yhat

def get_iris_data():
    """ Read the iris data set and split them into training and test sets """
    iris   = datasets.load_iris()
    data   = iris["data"]
    target = iris["target"]

    # Prepend the column of 1s for bias
    N, M  = data.shape
    all_X = np.ones((N, M + 1))
    all_X[:, 1:] = data

    # Convert into one-hot vectors
    num_labels = len(np.unique(target))
    all_Y = np.eye(num_labels)[target]  # One liner trick!
    return train_test_split(all_X, all_Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=RANDOM_SEED)

def get_modulus_data():

    all_X = np.round(np.random.random((150,5)))
    target = np.int_(all_X.sum(axis=1)%3)

    # Convert into one-hot vectors
    num_labels = len(np.unique(target))
    all_Y = np.eye(num_labels)[target]  # One liner trick!

    return train_test_split(all_X, all_Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=RANDOM_SEED)

def main():
    # train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = get_iris_data()
    train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = get_modulus_data()

    # Layer's sizes
    x_size = train_X.shape[1]   # Number of input nodes: 4 features and 1 bias
    h_size = 256                # Number of hidden nodes
    y_size = train_y.shape[1]   # Number of outcomes (3 iris flowers)

    # Symbols
    X = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, x_size])
    y = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, y_size])

    # Weight initializations
    w_1 = init_weights((x_size, h_size))
    w_2 = init_weights((h_size, h_size//2))
    w_3 = init_weights((h_size//2, y_size))

    # Forward propagation
    yhat    = forwardprop(X, w_1, w_2, w_3)
    predict = tf.argmax(yhat, dimension=1)

    # Backward propagation
    cost    = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(yhat, y))
    updates = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)

    # Run SGD
    sess = tf.Session()
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)

    for epoch in range(300):
        # Train with each example
        for i in range(len(train_X)-10):
            sess.run(updates, feed_dict={X: train_X[i: i + 10], y: train_y[i: i + 10]})

        train_accuracy = np.mean(np.argmax(train_y, axis=1) == sess.run(predict, feed_dict={X: train_X, y: train_y}))
        test_accuracy  = np.mean(np.argmax(test_y, axis=1) == sess.run(predict, feed_dict={X: test_X, y: test_y}))

        print("Epoch = %d, train accuracy = %.2f%%, test accuracy = %.2f%%"
              % (epoch + 1, 100. * train_accuracy, 100. * test_accuracy))

    sess.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the output from the program:

```
Epoch = 1, train accuracy = 44.00%, test accuracy = 50.00%
Epoch = 2, train accuracy = 48.00%, test accuracy = 40.00%
Epoch = 3, train accuracy = 50.00%, test accuracy = 46.00%
Epoch = 4, train accuracy = 44.00%, test accuracy = 40.00%
Epoch = 5, train accuracy = 46.00%, test accuracy = 48.00%
Epoch = 6, train accuracy = 45.00%, test accuracy = 38.00%
Epoch = 7, train accuracy = 45.00%, test accuracy = 44.00%
Epoch = 8, train accuracy = 53.00%, test accuracy = 40.00%
Epoch = 9, train accuracy = 48.00%, test accuracy = 46.00%
Epoch = 10, train accuracy = 44.00%, test accuracy = 38.00%
Epoch = 11, train accuracy = 48.00%, test accuracy = 48.00%
Epoch = 12, train accuracy = 44.00%, test accuracy = 32.00%
Epoch = 13, train accuracy = 42.00%, test accuracy = 48.00%
Epoch = 14, train accuracy = 47.00%, test accuracy = 46.00%
Epoch = 15, train accuracy = 50.00%, test accuracy = 44.00%
Epoch = 16, train accuracy = 48.00%, test accuracy = 44.00%
Epoch = 17, train accuracy = 49.00%, test accuracy = 40.00%
Epoch = 18, train accuracy = 48.00%, test accuracy = 36.00%
Epoch = 19, train accuracy = 48.00%, test accuracy = 40.00%
Epoch = 20, train accuracy = 47.00%, test accuracy = 32.00%
Epoch = 21, train accuracy = 48.00%, test accuracy = 38.00%
Epoch = 22, train accuracy = 43.00%, test accuracy = 38.00%
Epoch = 23, train accuracy = 48.00%, test accuracy = 46.00%
Epoch = 24, train accuracy = 50.00%, test accuracy = 44.00%
Epoch = 25, train accuracy = 51.00%, test accuracy = 34.00%
Epoch = 26, train accuracy = 52.00%, test accuracy = 36.00%
Epoch = 27, train accuracy = 54.00%, test accuracy = 42.00%
Epoch = 28, train accuracy = 50.00%, test accuracy = 34.00%
Epoch = 29, train accuracy = 47.00%, test accuracy = 38.00%
Epoch = 30, train accuracy = 48.00%, test accuracy = 40.00%
Epoch = 31, train accuracy = 52.00%, test accuracy = 42.00%
Epoch = 32, train accuracy = 51.00%, test accuracy = 34.00%
Epoch = 33, train accuracy = 49.00%, test accuracy = 42.00%
Epoch = 34, train accuracy = 49.00%, test accuracy = 42.00%
Epoch = 35, train accuracy = 50.00%, test accuracy = 46.00%
Epoch = 36, train accuracy = 48.00%, test accuracy = 40.00%
Epoch = 37, train accuracy = 50.00%, test accuracy = 44.00%
Epoch = 38, train accuracy = 46.00%, test accuracy = 38.00%
Epoch = 39, train accuracy = 46.00%, test accuracy = 46.00%
Epoch = 40, train accuracy = 50.00%, test accuracy = 40.00%
Epoch = 41, train accuracy = 53.00%, test accuracy = 38.00%
Epoch = 42, train accuracy = 50.00%, test accuracy = 42.00%
Epoch = 43, train accuracy = 49.00%, test accuracy = 42.00%
Epoch = 44, train accuracy = 48.00%, test accuracy = 38.00%
Epoch = 45, train accuracy = 51.00%, test accuracy = 40.00%
Epoch = 46, train accuracy = 50.00%, test accuracy = 46.00%
Epoch = 47, train accuracy = 49.00%, test accuracy = 46.00%
Epoch = 48, train accuracy = 48.00%, test accuracy = 38.00%
Epoch = 49, train accuracy = 52.00%, test accuracy = 46.00%
Epoch = 50, train accuracy = 47.00%, test accuracy = 52.00%
Epoch = 51, train accuracy = 44.00%, test accuracy = 40.00%
Epoch = 52, train accuracy = 51.00%, test accuracy = 44.00%
Epoch = 53, train accuracy = 48.00%, test accuracy = 40.00%
Epoch = 54, train accuracy = 49.00%, test accuracy = 38.00%
Epoch = 55, train accuracy = 48.00%, test accuracy = 38.00%
Epoch = 56, train accuracy = 49.00%, test accuracy = 42.00%
Epoch = 57, train accuracy = 50.00%, test accuracy = 38.00%
Epoch = 58, train accuracy = 48.00%, test accuracy = 44.00%
Epoch = 59, train accuracy = 51.00%, test accuracy = 42.00%
Epoch = 60, train accuracy = 48.00%, test accuracy = 34.00%
Epoch = 61, train accuracy = 47.00%, test accuracy = 42.00%
Epoch = 62, train accuracy = 48.00%, test accuracy = 42.00%
Epoch = 63, train accuracy = 49.00%, test accuracy = 42.00%
Epoch = 64, train accuracy = 53.00%, test accuracy = 48.00%
Epoch = 65, train accuracy = 51.00%, test accuracy = 42.00%
Epoch = 66, train accuracy = 48.00%, test accuracy = 36.00%
Epoch = 67, train accuracy = 49.00%, test accuracy = 46.00%
Epoch = 68, train accuracy = 52.00%, test accuracy = 42.00%
Epoch = 69, train accuracy = 50.00%, test accuracy = 38.00%
Epoch = 70, train accuracy = 49.00%, test accuracy = 42.00%
Epoch = 71, train accuracy = 50.00%, test accuracy = 44.00%
Epoch = 72, train accuracy = 50.00%, test accuracy = 38.00%
Epoch = 73, train accuracy = 48.00%, test accuracy = 46.00%
Epoch = 74, train accuracy = 52.00%, test accuracy = 48.00%
Epoch = 75, train accuracy = 48.00%, test accuracy = 40.00%
Epoch = 76, train accuracy = 48.00%, test accuracy = 38.00%
Epoch = 77, train accuracy = 51.00%, test accuracy = 42.00%
Epoch = 78, train accuracy = 45.00%, test accuracy = 40.00%
Epoch = 79, train accuracy = 46.00%, test accuracy = 38.00%
Epoch = 80, train accuracy = 51.00%, test accuracy = 42.00%
Epoch = 81, train accuracy = 47.00%, test accuracy = 42.00%
Epoch = 82, train accuracy = 53.00%, test accuracy = 44.00%
Epoch = 83, train accuracy = 49.00%, test accuracy = 38.00%
Epoch = 84, train accuracy = 49.00%, test accuracy = 38.00%
Epoch = 85, train accuracy = 52.00%, test accuracy = 30.00%
Epoch = 86, train accuracy = 49.00%, test accuracy = 36.00%
Epoch = 87, train accuracy = 48.00%, test accuracy = 44.00%
Epoch = 88, train accuracy = 46.00%, test accuracy = 40.00%
Epoch = 89, train accuracy = 48.00%, test accuracy = 44.00%
Epoch = 90, train accuracy = 50.00%, test accuracy = 34.00%
Epoch = 91, train accuracy = 53.00%, test accuracy = 32.00%
Epoch = 92, train accuracy = 51.00%, test accuracy = 40.00%
Epoch = 93, train accuracy = 43.00%, test accuracy = 44.00%
Epoch = 94, train accuracy = 48.00%, test accuracy = 40.00%
Epoch = 95, train accuracy = 50.00%, test accuracy = 44.00%
Epoch = 96, train accuracy = 48.00%, test accuracy = 38.00%
Epoch = 97, train accuracy = 50.00%, test accuracy = 50.00%
Epoch = 98, train accuracy = 47.00%, test accuracy = 46.00%
Epoch = 99, train accuracy = 52.00%, test accuracy = 40.00%
Epoch = 100, train accuracy = 50.00%, test accuracy = 36.00%
```

For comparison, here is the output from the iris dataset:

```
Epoch = 1, train accuracy = 71.00%, test accuracy = 68.00%
Epoch = 2, train accuracy = 81.00%, test accuracy = 80.00%
Epoch = 3, train accuracy = 80.00%, test accuracy = 90.00%
Epoch = 4, train accuracy = 87.00%, test accuracy = 92.00%
Epoch = 5, train accuracy = 91.00%, test accuracy = 86.00%
Epoch = 6, train accuracy = 90.00%, test accuracy = 94.00%
Epoch = 7, train accuracy = 96.00%, test accuracy = 92.00%
Epoch = 8, train accuracy = 89.00%, test accuracy = 86.00%
Epoch = 9, train accuracy = 92.00%, test accuracy = 92.00%
Epoch = 10, train accuracy = 92.00%, test accuracy = 94.00%
Epoch = 11, train accuracy = 96.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 12, train accuracy = 94.00%, test accuracy = 96.00%
Epoch = 13, train accuracy = 93.00%, test accuracy = 94.00%
Epoch = 14, train accuracy = 95.00%, test accuracy = 90.00%
Epoch = 15, train accuracy = 94.00%, test accuracy = 94.00%
Epoch = 16, train accuracy = 98.00%, test accuracy = 96.00%
Epoch = 17, train accuracy = 93.00%, test accuracy = 94.00%
Epoch = 18, train accuracy = 92.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 19, train accuracy = 94.00%, test accuracy = 100.00%
Epoch = 20, train accuracy = 94.00%, test accuracy = 96.00%
Epoch = 21, train accuracy = 96.00%, test accuracy = 96.00%
Epoch = 22, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 100.00%
Epoch = 23, train accuracy = 95.00%, test accuracy = 92.00%
Epoch = 24, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 100.00%
Epoch = 25, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 26, train accuracy = 96.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 27, train accuracy = 96.00%, test accuracy = 94.00%
Epoch = 28, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 29, train accuracy = 96.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 30, train accuracy = 95.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 31, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 100.00%
Epoch = 32, train accuracy = 96.00%, test accuracy = 100.00%
Epoch = 33, train accuracy = 95.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 34, train accuracy = 95.00%, test accuracy = 96.00%
Epoch = 35, train accuracy = 96.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 36, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 100.00%
Epoch = 37, train accuracy = 96.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 38, train accuracy = 96.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 39, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 40, train accuracy = 96.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 41, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 42, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 43, train accuracy = 98.00%, test accuracy = 96.00%
Epoch = 44, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 45, train accuracy = 94.00%, test accuracy = 100.00%
Epoch = 46, train accuracy = 98.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 47, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 100.00%
Epoch = 48, train accuracy = 96.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 49, train accuracy = 96.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 50, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 51, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 52, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 94.00%
Epoch = 53, train accuracy = 96.00%, test accuracy = 100.00%
Epoch = 54, train accuracy = 93.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 55, train accuracy = 94.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 56, train accuracy = 96.00%, test accuracy = 96.00%
Epoch = 57, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 58, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 59, train accuracy = 96.00%, test accuracy = 94.00%
Epoch = 60, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 61, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 96.00%
Epoch = 62, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 63, train accuracy = 96.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 64, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 65, train accuracy = 96.00%, test accuracy = 100.00%
Epoch = 66, train accuracy = 95.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 67, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 68, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 96.00%
Epoch = 69, train accuracy = 93.00%, test accuracy = 96.00%
Epoch = 70, train accuracy = 95.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 71, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 72, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 96.00%
Epoch = 73, train accuracy = 98.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 74, train accuracy = 96.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 75, train accuracy = 99.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 76, train accuracy = 96.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 77, train accuracy = 96.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 78, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 79, train accuracy = 98.00%, test accuracy = 96.00%
Epoch = 80, train accuracy = 95.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 81, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 82, train accuracy = 96.00%, test accuracy = 96.00%
Epoch = 83, train accuracy = 95.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 84, train accuracy = 96.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 85, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 86, train accuracy = 96.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 87, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 100.00%
Epoch = 88, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 89, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 96.00%
Epoch = 90, train accuracy = 98.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 91, train accuracy = 96.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 92, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 96.00%
Epoch = 93, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 100.00%
Epoch = 94, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 95, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 96.00%
Epoch = 96, train accuracy = 96.00%, test accuracy = 100.00%
Epoch = 97, train accuracy = 96.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 98, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 99, train accuracy = 97.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
Epoch = 100, train accuracy = 96.00%, test accuracy = 98.00%
```

Comment: A network that works with one dataset doesn't mean that will work with a different dataset. You need to adjust the learning capacity of the model (by adding or removing layers).

Comment: Thank you, I increased the number of layers and now I am getting much better results. I would give you points for your comment but I cant.

Comment: I will convert to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A network that works with one dataset doesn't mean that will work with a different dataset. Each network is designed with a specific learning capacity (approximately the number of parameters in the network) to match a given task or dataset.

If the learning capacity in the model is too low, then the model will underfit, and this is what you are seeting. Too much learning capacity and the model will overfit.

You need to adjust the learning capacity of the model (by adding or removing layers). In this case it seems you are underfitting so adding layers would help.